# Ruby inheritance and typing

Tags: ruby, class, module, typeerror, dynamic-typing

I am having trouble with some fundamental concepts in Ruby, specifically the interchangeability of a subclass for the superclass.

According to the Ruby documentation on classes, "Class" inherits from "Module".
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Class.html

```
class MyClassTest end
MyClassTest.is_a? Module # => true
```

However, when trying to use the `module` keyword to reopen a class defined with the keyword `class`, you get a TypeError that the class is not a module.

```
class MyClassTest end
module MyClassTest end # => TypeError: MyClassTest is not a module
```

This SO question has some excellent discussion surrounding subclasses vs subtypes, but I think it has lead me to more questions:
[Why can't classes be used as modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53449705/why-cant-classes-be-used-as-modules)

Generally, since Ruby is dynamically typed, I am confused by the existence of TypeErrors.

Specifically, in this case, I am extra confused as to how Ruby inheritance can result in a TypeError where the subclass cannot be substituted for the superclass. In my mind, subclassing is equivalent to subtyping in Ruby since the subclass will inherit the interface (methods and public attributes) of the superclass.

My current guess is that TypeError's are raised by the core Ruby library when certain assertions fail, and these TypeErrors don't necessarily have anything to do with Ruby's dynamic typing system, which is to say that typing is not a first-class concept in Ruby. The linked SO question raises excellent points about the diamond problem with multiple class inheritance, so it makes sense that Ruby would prevent the interchangeable usage of modules and classes when using the `module` or `class` keyword. Still, it feels like there are inconsistencies in my understanding of Ruby.

How can a "Class" input result in a TypeError when a "Module" object is expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic assertions are

- `Class` is a `Class` (`Class.is_a?(Class) #=> true`)
- `Class` is a `Module` (`Class.is_a?(Module) #=> true`)
- An instance of the class `Class` is a `Class` (`Class.new.is_a?(Class) #=> true`)
- An instance of the class `Class` is a `Module` (`Class.new.is_a?(Module) #=> true`)
- `Module` is a `Class` (`Module.is_a?(Class) #=> true`)
- By virtue `Module` is a `Module` (`Module.is_a?(Module) #=> true`)
- An instance of the class `Module` is a `Module` (`Module.new.is_a?(Module)  #=> true`)
- However An instance of the class `Module` is not a `Class` (`Module.new.is_a?(Class) #=> false`)
- an instance of the class `Class` is an instance of `Class` but not and instance of the class `Module` (`Class.new.instance_of?(Module) #=> false`)

`module` is a declaration for an instance of the class `Module` just as `class` is a declaration for an instance of the class `Class`.

If this were a method it might look like

```
def module(name,&block)
  raise TypeError if defined?(name) && !const_get(name).instance_of?(Module)
  obj = defined?(name) ? const_get(name) : const_set(name, Module.new)
  obj.instance_eval(&block)
end
```

`TypeError` exists to prevent ambiguity.

As in your case by using `class MyClassTest` you have created an instance of the class `Class` and that instance is called `MyTestClass`.

If you were also allowed to use `module MyTestClass`, in the same global context, then during usage I would be unaware if when calling `MyClassTest` I would be calling the `Class` or the `Module`.

The basic (**very basic**) difference is a `Class` can be instantiated (have instances) however a `Module` cannot.

For instance

```
Class.new.new #creates an instance of the anonymous class created by Class.new
Module.new.new # results in NoMethodError
```

Comment: I see, this provides some good context. However, based off these assertions:
"Class is a Module (Class.is_a?(Module) #=> true)",
"An instance of the class Class is a Module (Class.new.is_a?(Module) #=> true)"

I am still a bit confused by how 
"
class MyClassTest end
module MyClassTest end
"
Results in => TypeError: MyClassTest is not a module 

It makes sense to me that module and class definitions must be unique to avoid ambiguity, but since we are able to "reopen" class definitions, I am still a little confused as to why we can't reopen a class definition as a module.

Comment: @BrandonChow updated for additional clarity. While an instance of Class is a Module it is not an instance of Module

Answer (score 0):

I think the first point of confusion is the distinction between **usage** and **definition**.

The following code **defines** a class:

```
class C; end
```

If I see the above code, I expect to be able to instantiate C later:

```
C.new
```

However, imagine that C was already defined as a module:

```
# In one file:
module C; end

# Later in a different file:
class C; end    # C is actually a module

C.new           # fails
```

Ruby surfaces the problem (conflicting definitions of C) at the point where C is redefined as a class, rather than allowing the program to continue to where C is used.

The benefit of surfacing the problem earlier is generally the earlier an error is identified, the easier it is to find and fix its root cause (in this example, perhaps C is supposed to be a class after all, and thus the real issue is the `module C` definition).

Your second question is, I think, why a class cannot **always** be used as a module, for example why the following is prohibited:

```
class C; end
class A
  include C
end
```

The answer, I think, is the programming language starts with **concepts** which are then **implemented** using various constructs. We could describe classes and modules as follows:

- A class represents an object which has data and behavior (classic OOP definition).
- A module is a collection of behavior.

The `include` keyword extends a class with a module's *behavior*. In principle it is possible to take just a class's methods and add them to another class. But this operation doesn't *make sense* because a class is an object and its behavior together. Taking just the behavior goes against the concept of the class.

There are other programming languages which take different positions on this issue. For example, in JavaScript any function can be taken out of any class and invoked with an instance of any other class. This can be convenient in some situations and difficult to debug in others.

Comment: In JavaScript classes aren't exactly really things. Classes in JavaScript are syntactical sugar for first class functions that may or may not define other functions.